# Selenium IDE ignores the first element of the list when DragAndDropToObject

Tags: jquery, html, css, selenium, drag-and-drop

I have a page divided into 2 datagrids, left datagrid has a following structure:

```
<ul class="left_dg">
    <li>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

The right datagrid has a simple 'ul-li' structure and has a class="right_dg". I'm moving li-elements from the right with dragAndDropToObject to the left. It looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>dragAndDropToObject</td>
    <td>css=.right_dg > li:nth-child(2)</td>
    <td>css=.left_dg > li:nth-child(1) > ul</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dragAndDropToObject</td>
    <td>css=.right_dg > li:nth-child(2)</td>
    <td>css=.left_dg > li:nth-child(2) > ul</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dragAndDropToObject</td>
    <td>css=.right_dg > li:nth-child(2)</td>
    <td>css=.left_dg > li:nth-child(3) > ul</td>
</tr>
```

For some reason `<td>css=.left_dg > li:nth-child(1) > ul</td>` chooses a child of the second li-element, not the first one.

How could I reach a child of the first li? Many thanks for undrerstanding. I'm a novice with Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why such thing happens. But you could use the following code to reach the first element:

```
<tr>
     <td>mouseDownAt</td>
     <td>css=.right_dg > li:nth-child(2)</td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td>mouseMoveAt</td>
      <td>css=.left_dg > li:nth-child(1) > ul</td>
      <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td>mouseUpAt</td>
       <td>css=.left_dg > li:nth-child(1) > ul</td>
       <td></td>
</tr>
```

For second, third, etc. elements you can keep using dragAndDropToObject. That should work fine.